# how to make html table first row 'absolute'

Tags: jquery, css, html

i've got a table with 80 rows. how would i make the 1st row absolute? tried adding

```
position: absolute;
```

to the  but that didn't work. is there away to do it using css or jquery?

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <td style="position: absolute;"></td><td style="position: absolute;"></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: sorry I meant fixed not absolute. My bad

Comment: fyi the `<td>` in your `<thead>` should be a `<th>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Absolute positioning of a `<tr>` is possible (example: http://jsfiddle.net/thfz5/), but I'm not sure why you would want this...

Comment: You can also have a look at [this jQuery plugin](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you were looking for a way to make your first row to always get displayed on top even when page scrolls.
`absolute` is not the way to do that. Think like `position:absolute` "glues" your element to a position on a page, then if a page scrolls - your elements scroll with the page and gets out of view.

If you want your header to stick to top no matter what - you will need to involve some css tricks.

Here is an [example](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/) of such technique.

The easiest way would be, of course, to use `position: fixed`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8P3H7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
table thead tr:first-child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Just use the `first-child` pseudo element.

Or as discussed by *@mishik* then you may need that to be `position: fixed` or `position: relative; top: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing you can do if you want to scroll a table while the header will remain in place, but there are still problems with columns not aligning, and you have to make the header shorter so it doesn't go other the scroll bar:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
 <div style="overflow: auto;">
  <table>
   <thead  style="position:absolute;">
    <!-- Header here -->
   </thead>
    <tbody> <!-- body here --> </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```